# How to update the target cell of a CurrentRow in DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, parent-child

In my Windows Form Application, the `DataGridView` is updated from the `TextChanged_Event` of a textbox (bar code reading functionality). Every new row has values like **Product Name, Quantity, Unit Price**, and **Total Amount**. The **Product Name** and **Unit Price** values are coming from the database while I have set a default value of 1 for the **Quantity**. The value of **Total Amount** is the multiplication of *Quantity* and *Unit Price*.

Everything works fine until now and I am able to use the default 1 value for the sale **Quantity** of each item. However, if I want to sell an item more than once, then I need to replace this default quantity value with a custom value.

To simplify this process, I have used a **Child Form** with a single textbox and a button that will allow my user to put a custom value for the Quantity column which should replace the default 1 value of Quantity column.

I have tried different approaches with no luck. Because *I am showing the Child Form at that part of the Sale process where the application has to look for a duplicate product in the DataGridView*. If an item is already present in the DataGridView, the application asks for adding it again and when the user clicks on the Yes Button, the **Child Form** is shown.

So it makes my logic meaningless because after showing and making do with the custom Quantity value textbox on the Child Form, I can't access the variable on parent form for replacing its default 1 value with this custom quantity.

My code is working fine but I just need some improvement in the logic so that I can easily replace the default Quantity value with the custom value from the Child Form.

Here is my code:

```
public void FillCurrentSoldItemGrid(string barCode)
    {
        string columnList = "ProductName, UnitPrice";
        DataRow dr = NewSale.SelectByItemCode(columnList, barCode);
        if (dr == null)
        {
            //show error message
            return;
        }
        // check duplicate value in DataGridView
        string productName = dr[0].ToString();
        if (dgvSoldItems.RowCount > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in dgvSoldItems.Rows)
            {
                if (dgvRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString().CompareTo(productName) == 0)
                {
                    if (DataAccess.AskUser("This item is already present in the grid?", "Confirm Item Quantity Update") == true)
                    {
            //my child form code
                        using (var customSaleQuantity = new frmCustomSaleQuantity())
                        {
                            var result = customSaleQuantity.ShowDialog();
                            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                            {
                //need to assign this value of the customQuantity string to int quantity which is holding a default 1 value)
                                string customQuantity = customSaleQuantity.GetCustomQuantity;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    //value of string customQuantity to be assigned to int quantity.
        int quantity = 1;
        int unitPrice = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1]);

        DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
        row.CreateCells(dgvAllSoldItems);

        row.Cells[0].Value = productName;
        row.Cells[1].Value = quantity;
        row.Cells[2].Value = unitPrice;
        row.Cells[3].Value = (quantity * unitPrice);

        dgvAllSoldItems.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

And here is the code from my Child Form:

```
public string GetCustomQuantity
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private void btnProceedWithNewItemQuantity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.GetCustomQuantity = txtChooseSaleQuantity.Text.Trim();
        this.Close();
    }
```

I am new to c# and I don't have any idea of how to replace the default 1 value of quantity with the custom value if a duplicate item is detected. This is really important task and my deadline is almost over.

Any help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: @Filburt, here is my question

Comment: Not to dissuade you from using a “child” form for this… however, when scanning, is there some reason you do not simply increment the quantity value of the duplicate item instead of displaying the “child” form? In addition, if the user is allowed to change any “quantity” value in the grid, it would appear this “child” form becomes unnecessary. Just a thought.

Comment: @JohnG Using a numeric-Up/Down within the target cell for all rows can also work for me, but as per the application requirements, they won't be that much professional. Additionally, using this childForm can simplify the job, so why I am interested in working on it.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to improve logic; however, one way is to apply Object Oriented  Programming (OOP) concept.
Define a static class to hold global variables, fields and functions.
Once a user enters data in the child form, pass that information to the static class getter/setter methods. Also, in your static class you can define a public function to process data.
Do not forget to refresh GridView to view the updated information.
The main reason I recommend using a static class that you can call public attributes, methods from anywhere in your application and you would not need to create a instance of class object.

```
static class Globals
{
    // global int 
    public static int counter;

    // global function
    public static string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}

Globals.counter = 10;
int localcounter = Globals.counter;
string somestring = Globals.HelloWorld();
Globals.counter2 = 30;
int localcounter2 = Globals.counter2;
```